# JSF2 + Primefaces + PDF

Tags: pdf, primefaces, popup, response

i have a .xhtml page:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{suspendBean.getSuspendBeanHandler()}" />
```

and the method getSuspendBeanHandler();

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baosPDF=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

ec.responseReset(); 
ec.setResponseContentType("application/pdf"); 
ec.setResponseContentLength(baosPDF.size());

ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");


OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();
.....


baosPDF.writeTo(output);

fc.responseComplete();
```

I want to show PDF in a new windows browser o most likely a new popup.

Comment: And the problem is? Please put **that** in the title.

Comment: Reason: jsf2 + PrimeFaces + pdf is meaningless as a problem description